# Take only non zero and non negative arguments in UDF of excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, arguments, user-defined-functions, freeze

I have created a UDF to iterate an equation. The UDF is working fine. But, if the argument(s) is assigned zero or negative, say W = 0, then the excel freezes completely. I want to stop the execution of UDF or display errors if the argument(s) is zero or negative and prevent the file from freezing. Please help

```
Function myfunc(Q, W, n, s As Double) As Double
Dim Q_Cal As Double

' to initialize the loop
D = 0.001
Q_Cal = 0.001

While Q_Cal < Q
    D = D + 0.001
    Q_Cal = ((W * D) / n) * ((W * D) / (2 * D + W)) ^ (2 / 3) * s ^ 0.5
Wend

myfunc = Round(D, 3)

End Function
```

Comment: Just verify them at the start - eg `If Q <=0 Or W <=0 or n <= 0 or s <= 0 then` If you want to return an error value, declare the function as variant. Also note that all your input variables other than `s` are `Variant`.

Comment: Also, declare all your arguments: `Function myfunc(Q As Double, W As Double, n As Double, s As Double) As Double`. And `D` as well.